# SharePoint 2010 - Create new user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

There is an existing sharepoint 2010 site that a consulting firm did for us. I need to add some users to sharepoint that aren't in AD. Is it possible to have sharepoint manage the users? If so can it easily be setup or do I have to edit configs and what not. I found a few blog posts such as this  one http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/05/07/configuring-claims-and-forms-based-authentication-for-use-with-a.aspx but it seems like a lot of work. I'd rather not use NTLM since the users will change often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to have sharepoint
>   manage the users?

No, you can't just add users directly to sharepoint. SharePoint users must come from some kind of store, AD, ADAM, ADFS, database, or something. Having them in a database is probably your best bet.

> If so can it easily be setup or do I
>   have to edit configs and what not.

Unfortuately, to add another user store to sharepoint, you will need to edit the web.configs

I am going to take a guess that you will probably also need to convert you existing web applications from classic to claims

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx

Once you have setup everything, there are many components that can manage the users, open source and paid, or you could roll your own.

eg

http://fba.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=basic%20FBA%20user%20and%20role%20management&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Thanks. I figured I would have to go this route. I'm going to add them to local machine for now then work on the config later.